# Hiding API keys in JS setup

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, environment-variables, api-key

I'm creating a simple UI with an HTML+CSS+JS setup that uses a third-party API requiring a key and I'd like to keep the key in a file that I can `gitignore` and access from my Javascript file. I'm not going to be deploying this project, I just want to be able to push it to GitHub without temporarily deleting the variable before every commit.

All responses I've found are related to setups with Node.js, React/Webpack, or other server setups, but I don't have a server or transpiler and don't want to add a bunch of cruft and configurations just for this. Is there a way to do that? I tried storing it in a separate JS file and import/export, but either I couldn't get the syntax right or what I was trying needed a transpiler.  Every attempt variation resulted in a syntax error or undefined variable.

**Key information:**

1. This is project run entirely locally--as in, just opening `index.html` in my browser--so I don't think I need to worry about the key being exposed in the client.
2. My setup pretty much just includes `index.html`, `main.js`, and `style.css`.
3. I want to push the project to GitHub, so I want to store the api key as a variable in a file separate from `main.js` that I can add to `.gitignore` but access in `main.js`.
4. I'm keeping this as simple as possible without frameworks, etc. Unless it's super simple and lightweight, I don't want to add libraries just to get this working.

Comment: What Serverless provider are you using?  AWS Lambda?

Comment: @Paul I shouldn't have said serverless in the initial title. I meant that literally, as in, "I have no server at all." No backend is involved, just index.html, styles.css, main.js and running it by opening index.html in the browser. I couldn't figure out how to configure a `.env` file without Node or some sort of transpiler.
I think the answer is either so basic that I'm missing it or it's not possible creating something overly engineered

Comment: If that's true, then you're sending your API key to the client and therefore everyone using your application will have it if they want it.

Comment: I'm not deploying it for anyone to use, I'm literally opening the local index.html file in my browser, so I don't think I need to worry about security. I'd like to publicly push the project to GitHub, though, so I want to be able to keep the key in a file that can be ignored by git.

Comment: Updated answer based on this new information.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your best bet is to pull whatever secrets you need from the environment itself, either your environment variables or a secrets store.

The specific implementation will depend on what serverless provider you're using, but for example AWS Lambda lets you configure env vars:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/env_variables.html

and you can use the Key Management Service or Parameter Store depending on your preference and requirements:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/the-right-way-to-store-secrets-using-parameter-store/

---

Leaving the above in place in case folks find this via looking at the Serverless tag. Updates below based on the updated question.

So, if I understand the updated question correctly, you want to check in all your code to git except the API key, serve the files only on your local file system and have that local copy be able to access the API key.

The simplest way to do this would be to just have another .js file that defines the variable(s) in question like so:

```
// config.js
var config = { // this should be const instead if you're using ES6 standards
  apiKey : '123456789XYZ'
}
```

Then, in index.html have another script tag that calls that before any scripts that need the config, e.g.:

```
  <script src='./config.js'></script>
  <script src='./main.js'></script>
</body>
```

In main.js you will then be able to reference the variable `config` for use, and similarly you can .gitignore 'config.js'.

Comment: If you were to deploy this, then wouldn't the config.js file also need to be publicly accessible to be able to read it from the index page? Which would also make the apikey public?

Comment: Yes, but if you check the updated question, he was specifically looking for a solution for a localhost deployment, not something to publish.

Comment: I gathered that it was mainly a way to keep the api key out of the repo. I found this question when looking for a way to hid a api key when using JS. I found that there is no way without using some kind of server side language.

Comment: @Sl4rtib4rtf4st yes, that's correct.  Though you could potentially use Firebase's approach, which is to have a 'public' API key that intersects w/ the user identity on the server to figure out permissions and such.

Comment: Okay hadn't heard about that before. Thanks, I'll look into that.

Comment: I really get the question was for a "local" situation, but honestly, the security of the response isn't appropriate.

Answer (score -8):

If you use MVC, try to write in php variabel. Than open in script javasript with echo ...

Comment: How that's secure? Literally anybody can make request to that .php file and see that secret.